# Adding a package in Julia "ERROR The following package names could not be resolved"

Tags: julia

When trying to add a package on Julia, I keep getting these message.

```
Pkg.add("Taro")
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Taro (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

The warning only pops up when installing certain packages. 
I have also tried to use:
get glone http://aviks.github.io/Taro.jl/ , but has not worked neither.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Rodrigo

Comment: write what `Taro.jl` functionality you need - maybe there is a workaround for you.

Answer (score 3):

The package is registered but doesn't seem to be ready for Julia 1.0.

You can (force) add it from it's github repository. It's located at https://github.com/aviks/Taro.jl. Hence, you can either

```
] add https://github.com/aviks/Taro.jl
```

or equivalently

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("https://github.com/aviks/Taro.jl")
```

However, building the package will fail on Julia 1.0. Note that the URL that you mention, http://aviks.github.io/Taro.jl/, is only the packages documentation.

Comment: Thanks crstnbr for the answer. I tried both suggestions, however I now get another error: "The following package coul not be resolved: *DataArrays(not found in project, manifest, or registry).

Comment: I'm not sure why you get this. I have no problem adding `DataArrays` myself. Note, however, my comment above, that the package won't work on 1.0 anyway. You should probably tell us what feature from Taro.jl you actually need. Maybe there is some other package that does the job.

Comment: Thanks, crstnbr. You are right, I have installed a different package (CSV.jl). What is puzzling to me is that I get different the same error when I try to install other packages, but not with all packages.